# Internationalization in xcode4.5 with base internationalization

Tags: ios, xcode, internationalization, xcode4.5

Im new to internationalization

i followed this steps ,

- Clicked the "make localized" on my nib files that needed localization
- Went to project settings , enabled base internationalization

[image]

- Added a few languages
- Settings controller and Settings xib looks like this

[image]

- Changed some strings in settings.strings(another language)
- build and run , change language
- at the settings controller, changes are not reflected

checking my finder's project folder i see the en , cn , ko project folders

I seem to be missing an important step here

Comment: Check [Use single storyboard file for Base Internationalization in iOS 6](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1467446), you will find a detail way to do what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look this:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp/InternationalizeYourApp.html

This tutorial will help you localize the following text:

1. The text in the storyboards for both languages
2. The string that the app constructs and displays when users click the Hello button
3. The name of the app as displayed to users